# Using Iterators within the WebSearch Command

Tags: web-access, iterators, procedural-programming, webservices

I am currently trying to use the WebSearch command within Mathematica to search names from a Dataset that I have already imported. The names that I am trying to search are located in the 4th column of the Dataset, and I would like to program a "While" loop in which each of these names are run through the WebSearch command.

After I imported the Dataset (which I have assigned as "rawdata" here, and have included a portion of in the image below),

[image]

I wrote the following code to try to begin this name-searching loop:

```
i = 1
While[i < 6, i++;
 WebSearch[rawdata[[i, 4]]]]
```

Although for some reason, using the iterator with WebSearch does not seem to work. I know that WebSearch works when a specific cell is designated within a Dataset (i.e. WebSearch[rawdata[[2,4]]] does return the search for the name in that particular position in the "rawdata" Dataset, but I need to get it to work with an iterator so that I can get a loop going).

Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you please provide an example data set for `rawdata`?  Otherwise, the example is very abstract and people might not be willing to dig into this. Btw., what about `WebSearch/@rawdata[[All, 4]]`?

Comment: Thanks @HenrikSchumacher. I have updated the question with a snippet image of the Dataset, which I think provides enough of a glimpse. WebSearch/@rawdata[[All, 4]] is a good idea for a solution, so thank you for your great input there. Although I am still just trying to understand if the WebSearch command can work with iterators in general. Please let me know if you can shed any light on that, now that the Dataset image is included. Thanks so much for your help.